# ajax.actionlink post form not showing ckeditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor, asp.net-mvc-ajax

After Using the Ajax.ActionLink As

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "AddEdit", new { @id = id, @recId = item.EncyclopediaID }, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "listForm" }, new { @class = "edit_icon", @title = "edit this item" })
```

And When Controller Go to AddEdit Page There i have Uploaded the File and want to show the Ckeditor.

So i use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEdit", "Encyclopedia", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   /////////other code//////////////////
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description,"CKEditor")
}
```

Now if i use  to show the @Html.ActionLink instead of @Ajax.Actionlink Ckeditor Shows perfectly and in Ajax call it showed like a textarea.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because resource files required for ckeditor to work correctly (eg: `css` , `javascript`) cannot be downloaded with an ajax call.
try referencing the required resource files in layout view page and try again.

**Edit :**

maybe you have placed integration code in document.ready function, thus after ajax request completed and you markup changed, the new markup (eg:your new input element) is not configured as ckeditor input.so try calling ckeditor integration code after ajax success.

Comment: Not Working @Behnam I have included them in Layout but i think its not fault of Resource loading because i referenced them on the layout page and still same problem repeats.

Comment: then check to see if any javascript error is there , causing script execution to stop (check developer tool console).

Comment: not getting any error. I have used the Editor template and when it executes debugger goes to That code and no error occured.